# Redirect the selenium link to another link

Tags: python, selenium

When I press a button using selenium, it redirects me to a new page. I want my selenium to redirect to same link also. How can I do it?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Secure Login")]').click()
```

is a button I am clicking. It is redirecting me to a new page. I want selenium to get the same link and point to new page.

Comment: can you please provide more details?

Comment: Do you mean _when I press a button in my browser_?

Comment: So when you call `click()` on that button in Selenium, it redirects you to a new page.  So now you're on the new page.  Asking selenium to take you to the same page again seems redundant.

Comment: By page, you probably mean a browser window/tab? The links opens in a new tab, but you want it to be opened in the same browser tab?

Comment: this is because `target` attribute for this link set to `'_blank'` but not `'_self'`. I guess you can try to find proper `JS` code to execute in `execute_script()` method. This will allow you to open link in same tab

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you switch to new window, not sure about python but in java its like:

```
String currentState = driver.getWindowHandle().toString();
for (String handles : driver.getWindowHandles())
{
    if (!handles.equalsIgnoreCase(currentState))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handles);
    }
}
```

You can do same in python.

Answer (score 0):

`WebDriver` creates and interface between selenium and your web browser. You don't need to handle anything separately in selenium if everything is happening in the same tab and it's just a navigation to a different link.

Though if your link is opening to a different tab, you will need to switch tabs. Before communicating with the elements over the new page.